# Enhance the visibility of my contour plot with most its values close to zero

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, normalization, colormap

I'm trying to plot a contour plot. The problem with this is that most of the matrix has 0 values and few values are important. This resulted in a very dull graph with little visible data. I tried to normalize it using LogNorm() but this made my plot white because of the zero values.
I would like to enhance the colors so that I highlight more the values close to zero (we're talking about values of the order of 1e-7) and at the same time maybe increase the color area in the heat map. The final plot should be similar to a waterfall plot (blue background with colored lines).
[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBP1L.png)
[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JLWR.png)

```
X , Y = np.meshgrid(frequencies, speeds)
Z = freq_speed_grid.to_numpy()
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
levels=np.linspace(Z.min(), Z.max(), 50)
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap = "jet", norm=Normalize(), levels=levels)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Speed (RPM)")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

---

**TL;DR** Use `matplotlib.color.LogNorm`

---

Let's import the usual stuff and make up a `Z` array most close to zero but with some LARGE values just there — `Z` goes from 10<sup>-3</sup> to 10<sup>5</sup>

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10000, 101)
y = np.linspace(0, 15000, 151)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x/10000, y/15000)
Z= 99999*X**15*Y**15+0.001
```

Now plot it as you did

```
fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots()
cf0 = ax0.contourf(x, y, Z, levels=11, vmin=0, vmax=100000)
cb0 = fig0.colorbar(cf0)
cb0.set_ticks((0, 20000, 40000, 60000, 80000, 100000),
              labels='0 20000 40000 60000 80000 100000'.split())
```

[image]

Next, a homebrew rescaling of data, I plot the `log10`, care must be taken to rescale the labels

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
cf1 = ax1.contourf(x, y, np.log10(Z), levels=11,
      norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=-3, vmax=5, clip=True))
cb1 = fig1.colorbar(cf1)
cb1.set_ticks(range(-3, 6), 
              labels=['%.4g'%pow(10, c) for c in range(-3,6)])
```

[image]

It's good, but cumbersome. Luckily Matplotlib has what we need, it's `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm`, and it does what it promises

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
cf2 = ax2.contourf(x, y, Z, levels=11, norm=LogNorm(vmax=1E5, clip=1))
cb2 = fig2.colorbar(cf2)
```

[image]

It's a pity that it doesn't format properly the labels on the colorbar, but that's easy to fix

```
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
cf3 = ax3.contourf(x, y, Z, levels=11, norm=LogNorm(vmax=1E5, clip=1))
cb3 = fig3.colorbar(cf3)
cb3.set_ticks(cb3.get_ticks(),
              labels=['%.2g'%c for c in cb2.get_ticks()])
```

[image]